# local variables in the "submethod"

Tags: java, scope

This is my code:

```
public void viewFlight() {
  int select;
  String option;
  String newOrigin = null;
  viewFlightOrigin();
}

public void viewFlightOrigin() {
  option = console.nextLine();
  switch (select) {
    case 1:
      System.out.println("=======================================");
      System.out.println("city of origin: Melbourne");
      System.out.println("=======================================");
      newOrigin = "Melbourne";
      break;

    // ...
  }
}
```

How to use local variables in the `viewFlight()` to be used again in the `viewFlightOrigin()` without declaring the variables in the field or re-declaring again in the `viewFlightOrigin()`?

Comment: pass `select` as an argument to `viewFlightOrigin`. Seems like exercise.

Comment: I think that once you get your method ready, you should post it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for review.

Comment: By the way, is this some kind of a homework assignment? If it is, you should tag it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do if you do not need to *modify* the variable would be to pass it down as a parameter to the function:

```
viewFlightOrigin(newOrigin);

public void viewFlightOrigin(String option) {
    // ...
}
```

If you need to modify the variable, you can return the new value from the method:

```
newOrigin = viewFlightOrigin(origin);

public String viewFlightOrigin(String option) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use and modify the same "variables" in two different methods, then they must not be local variables, they're instance *attributes* of the class.

Alternatively, you could pass them as parameters to `viewFlightOrigin()`, just remember that any modification to the variables inside `viewFlightOrigin()` will *not* be visible after the method returns back to `viewFlight()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.
public void viewFlight()
{
  .....
  viewFlightOrigin(option);
  ....
}

2.declare a instance field then it's not a local variable
```

Answer (score 0):

Using parameter:

```
public void viewFlight() {
    int select;
    String option;

    viewFlightOrigin(select, option);
}

public void viewFlightOrigin(int select, String option) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only instance variables are available across different methods. Local variable are having scope till that method not out side of the method.